# How to compare characters in Swift efficiently

Tags: swift, string, character

I have a function in Swift that computes the [hamming distance](http:///https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of two strings and then puts them into a connected graph if the result is 1.

*For example, **read** to **hear** returns a hamming distance of 2 because **`read[0] != hear[0]`** and **`read[3] != hear[3]`**.*

At first, I thought my function was taking a long time because of the quantity of input (8,000+ word dictionary), but I knew that several minutes was too long. So, I rewrote my same algorithm in Java, and the computation took merely 0.3s.

I have tried writing this in Swift two different ways:

---

### Way 1 - Substrings

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return self[Range(i ..< i + 1)]
    }

}

private func getHammingDistance(w1: String, w2: String) -> Int {
    if w1.length != w2.length { return -1 }

    var counter = 0
    for i in 0 ..< w1.length {
        if w1[i] != w2[i] { counter += 1 }
    }

    return counter
}
```

**Results:** 434 seconds

---

### Way 2 - Removing Characters

```
private func getHammingDistance(w1: String, w2: String) -> Int {
    if w1.length != w2.length { return -1 }

    var counter = 0
    var c1 = w1, c2 = w2      // need to mutate
    let length = w1.length

    for i in 0 ..< length {
        if c1.removeFirst() != c2.removeFirst() { counter += 1 }
    }

    return counter
}
```

**Results:** 156 seconds

---

### Same Thing in Java

**Results:** 0.3 seconds

---

### Where it's being called

```
var graph: Graph

func connectData() {
    let verticies = graph.canvas // canvas is Array<Node>
                                 // Node has key that holds the String

    for vertex in 0 ..< verticies.count {
        for compare in vertex + 1 ..< verticies.count {
            if getHammingDistance(w1: verticies[vertex].key!, w2: verticies[compare].key!) == 1 {
                graph.addEdge(source: verticies[vertex], neighbor: verticies[compare])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

156 seconds is still far too inefficient for me. What is the absolute most efficient way of comparing characters in Swift? Is there a possible workaround for computing hamming distance that involves not comparing characters?

---

### Edit

**Edit 1:** I am taking an entire dictionary of 4 and 5 letter words and creating a connected graph where the edges indicate a hamming distance of 1. Therefore, I am comparing 8,000+ words to each other to generate edges.

**Edit 2:** Added method call.

Comment: It seems really odd that "way 2" is faster than "way 1". Why would it be faster to modify the strings? See if "way 1" is faster if you use the `length` variable like you did in "way 2".

Comment: @LoganJahnke There's a reason in Swift 3 that strings don't have a subscript that takes an Int. That extension you cooked up does a linear scan through the whole string. The unicode correctness of Swift Strings precludes constant time access by index. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID301

Comment: @rmaddy it's about 10 seconds faster, but still in the 400+ seconds range

Comment: It would help people if you updated your question with code that calls your `getHammingDistance` method. Clearly you are calling it more than once.

Comment: Have you actually profiled the code? Are you sure the bottleneck is just in this one method?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I have ensured that it is my one method

Comment: Okay, how many compares do you have? 8500 * 8500?

Comment: Its a little less than that. I'm in `O(n^2 / 2)`. It comes out to be 8500 * 4250.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you chose a fixed length character model for your strings, methods and properties such as .count and .characters will have a complexity of O(n) or at best O(n/2) (where n is the string length).  If you were to store your data in an array of character (e.g. [Character] ), your functions would perform much better.

You can also combine the whole calculation in a single pass using the zip() function

```
let hammingDistance = zip(word1.characters,word2.characters)
                      .filter{$0 != $1}.count
```

but that still requires going through all characters of every word pair.

...

Given that you're only looking for Hamming distances of 1, there is a faster way to get to all the unique pairs of words:

The strategy is to group words by the 4 (or 5) patterns that correspond to one "missing" letter.  Each of these pattern groups defines a smaller scope for word pairs because words in different groups would be at a distance other than 1.

Each word will belong to as many groups as its character count.

For example :

```
"hear" will be part of the pattern groups:
"*ear", "h*ar", "he*r" and "hea*".
```

Any other word that would correspond to one of these 4 pattern groups would be at a Hamming distance of 1 from "hear".

Here is how this can be implemented:

```
// Test data 8500 words of 4-5 characters ...
var seenWords = Set<String>()
var allWords = try! String(contentsOfFile: "/usr/share/dict/words")
                     .lowercased()                        
                     .components(separatedBy:"\n")
                     .filter{$0.characters.count == 4 || $0.characters.count == 5}
                     .filter{seenWords.insert($0).inserted}
                     .enumerated().filter{$0.0 < 8500}.map{$1}

// Compute patterns for a Hamming distance of 1
// Replace each letter position with "*" to create patterns of
// one "non-matching" letter
public func wordH1Patterns(_ aWord:String) -> [String]
{
   var result       : [String]    = []
   let fullWord     : [Character] = aWord.characters.map{$0}
   for index in 0..<fullWord.count
   {
      var pattern    = fullWord
      pattern[index] = "*" 
      result.append(String(pattern))                     
   }
   return result
}

// Group words around matching patterns
// and add unique pairs from each group
func addHamming1Edges()
{
   // Prepare pattern groups ...
   // 
   var patternIndex:[String:Int] = [:]
   var hamming1Groups:[[String]]  = []
   for word in allWords
   {
      for pattern in wordH1Patterns(word)
      {
         if let index = patternIndex[pattern]
         { 
           hamming1Groups[index].append(word) 
         }
         else
         {
           let index = hamming1Groups.count
           patternIndex[pattern] = index
           hamming1Groups.append([word])
         }        
      }
   }

   // add edge nodes ...
   //
   for h1Group in hamming1Groups
   {
       for (index,sourceWord) in h1Group.dropLast(1).enumerated()
       {
          for targetIndex in index+1..<h1Group.count
          { addEdge(source:sourceWord, neighbour:h1Group[targetIndex]) } 
       }
   }
}
```

On my 2012 MacBook Pro, the 8500 words go through 22817 (unique) edge pairs in 0.12 sec.

[EDIT] to illustrate my first point, I made a "brute force" algorithm using arrays of characters instead of Strings :

```
   let wordArrays = allWords.map{Array($0.unicodeScalars)}
   for i in 0..<wordArrays.count-1
   {
      let word1 = wordArrays[i]
      for j in i+1..<wordArrays.count
      {
         let word2 = wordArrays[j]
         if word1.count != word2.count { continue }

         var distance = 0
         for c in 0..<word1.count 
         {
            if word1[c] == word2[c] { continue }
            distance += 1
            if distance > 1 { break }
         }
         if distance == 1
         { addEdge(source:allWords[i], neighbour:allWords[j]) }
      }
   }
```

This goes through the unique pairs in 0.27 sec.   The reason for the speed difference is the internal model of Swift Strings which is not actually an array of equal length elements (characters) but rather a chain of varying length encoded characters (similar to the UTF model where special bytes indicate that the following 2 or 3 bytes are part of a single character.  There is no simple Base+Displacement indexing of such a structure which must always be iterated from the beginning to get to the Nth element.

Note that I used unicodeScalars instead of Character because they are 16 bit fixed length representations of characters that allow a direct binary comparison.  The Character type isn't as straightforward and take longer to compare.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
extension String {
    func hammingDistance(to other: String) -> Int? {
        guard self.characters.count == other.characters.count else { return nil }

        return zip(self.characters, other.characters).reduce(0) { distance, chars in
            distance + (chars.0 == chars.1 ? 0 : 1)
        }
    }
}

print("read".hammingDistance(to: "hear")) // => 2
```

Comment: `a.characters` and `b.characters` can be saved in the local variable tho.

Comment: @user28434 To what end?

Comment: `characters` property getter may have computational overhead

Comment: @user28434 I'll leave that to the compiler, and correct it if the profiler shows it's an actual issue.

Comment: This version uses about 4 times more computation then the one I suggestion

Comment: @BencePattogato And why's that? It's one iteration through both strings to compare their counts, and then another to compare their characters

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe sg. about functional programming or blocks

Comment: Unfortunately, your algorithm finished in 161 seconds for my problem. Looks pretty and concise though.

Comment: What are your two strings?

Comment: @LoganJahnke You're doing all this testing on an optimized build... right? And you've isolated this as being the slow part of the code?

Comment: @Alexander yessir

Comment: @yessir Comparing 2 million character strings just took 1.19s.

Answer (score 1):

The following code executed in 0.07 secounds for 8500 characters:

```
func getHammingDistance(w1: String, w2: String) -> Int {
    if w1.characters.count != w2.characters.count {
        return -1
    }

    let arr1 = Array(w1.characters)
    let arr2 = Array(w2.characters)

    var counter = 0
    for i in 0 ..< arr1.count {
        if arr1[i] != arr2[i] { counter += 1 }
    }

    return counter
}
```

Comment: 1 iteration through `w1` and `w2` compare the counts, 1 iteration through `w1` to needlessly copy its contents into an array, then the same for w2, then one iteration to compare the characters. That's 5 iterations, as opposed to my solution's 3.

Comment: still faster :)

Comment: It's more efficient than my algorithm, but still not nearly as fast as its Java counterpart. Resulted in 134 seconds.

Comment: With what input data? Compiler optimization enabled?

Answer (score 1):

After some messing around, I found a faster solution to @Alexander's answer (and my previous broken answer)

```
extension String {
    func hammingDistance(to other: String) -> Int? {
        guard !self.isEmpty, !other.isEmpty, self.characters.count == other.characters.count else {
            return nil
        }

        var w1Iterator = self.characters.makeIterator()
        var w2Iterator = other.characters.makeIterator()

        var distance = 0;
        while let w1Char = w1Iterator.next(), let w2Char = w2Iterator.next()  {
            distance += (w1Char != w2Char) ? 1 : 0
        }
        return distance
    }
}
```

For comparing strings with a million characters, on my machine it's 1.078 sec compared to 1.220 sec, so roughly a 10% improvement. My guess is this is due to avoiding `.zip` and the slight overhead of `.reduce` and tuples

Answer (score 0):

*broken*, see new answer

My approach:

```
private func getHammingDistance(w1: String, w2: String) -> Int {
    guard w1.characters.count == w2.characters.count else {
        return -1
    }
    let countArray: Int = w1.characters.indices
        .reduce(0, {$0 + (w1[$1] == w2[$1] ? 0 : 1)})
    return countArray
}
```

comparing 2 strings of 10,000 random characters took 0.31 seconds

To expand a bit: it should only require one iteration through the strings, adding as it goes.

Also it's way more concise .

Comment: Your code does not compile. And even fixed, indexes taken from `testText.characters.indices` are valid only for `testText`. Your code (if fixed) works only in some very restricted condition.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `print(getHammingDistance(w1: "", w2: "abc"))`

Comment: I fixed the variable names and am working on a solution to the problem. Also looking forward to Swift 4.

Comment: @OOPer See new answer. Found a better and fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, calling .characters repeatedly takes time. If you convert all of the strings once, it should help.

```
func connectData() {
    let verticies = graph.canvas // canvas is Array<Node>
                                 // Node has key that holds the String
    // Convert all of the keys to utf16, and keep them
    let nodesAsUTF = verticies.map { $0.key!.utf16 }

    for vertex in 0 ..< verticies.count {
        for compare in vertex + 1 ..< verticies.count {
            if getHammingDistance(w1: nodesAsUTF[vertex], w2: nodesAsUTF[compare]) == 1 {
                graph.addEdge(source: verticies[vertex], neighbor: verticies[compare])
            }
        }
    }
}

// Calculate the hamming distance of two UTF16 views
func getHammingDistance(w1: String.UTF16View, w2: String.UTF16View) -> Int {
    if w1.count != w2.count {
        return -1
    }

    var counter = 0
    for i in w1.startIndex ..< w1.endIndex {
        if w1[i] != w1[i] {
            counter += 1
        }
    }
    return counter
}
```

I used UTF16, but you might want to try UTF8 depending on the data. Since I don't have the dictionary you are using, please let me know the result!